# What to say if a decision problem is not NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $O$ be an optimisation problem and $P$ its decision variant.
I know that $O$ is said to be NP-hard if $P$ is $NP-$complete.
However, what to say about $O$ when the decision problem $P$ is no more in the class $NP$, and thus it's no more $NP-$complete(the algorithm of deciding is pseudo-polynomial and there is no better alternatives)?

Comment: `I know that  is said to be NP-hard if  is −complete` No. $NP$-hard means that every problem from $NP$ is polynomially reducible to this problem. It doesn't mean that its decision problem is $NP$-complete (i.e. lies in $NP$).

Comment: Please check https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/nphard.html, "When a decision version of a combinatorial optimization problem is proved to belong to the class of NP-complete problems, then the optimization version is NP-hard. "

Comment: The wording matters. "$X$ is said to be $Y$ when $Z$" is a **definition** of $Y$. The citation you've shared means **implication**: "when $Z$, then $Y$" - which means that $Z$ doesn't have to hold for $Y$ to be true. In this case, it's not necessary for decision problem to be NP-complete, for the optimization problem to be NP-hard.

Comment: @Dimitry it seems that your comments starts to constitute an answer. Maybe you would like to get actual upvote?